# Yii2 download pdf with mail attachment at same time using kartik\mpdf\Pdf

Tags: email, pdf, download, yii2, email-attachments

I am using kartik\mpdf\Pdf lib. to generate pdf in yii2 of dynamic data. I am able to download file but I also want to send pdf attachment in mail also at the same time I am download file. Can anyone suggest me good way to do that. what I was thinking to firstly store content in variable and send that to mail then make it download

```
$pdfAttachment = $pdf->render();
$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('attachment-template');
$message->setFrom('from@email.com');
$message->attach($pdfAttachment);
$message->setTo('sendto@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('Message subject')
        ->send();

    return $pdfAttachment;
```

but this is not working. can anyone suggest me where I am lacking.

Comment: And whats the error or 'not working symptoms'?

Comment: its working now thanks. will post answer here soon

Comment: Well we are still waiting for you to post the answer....

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by following steps:

1. Create a pdf generate function with parameter 'destination'.
2. Call this function with parameter 'S' You will get the pdf content as string.
3. Send it:

   ```
   $email = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()   
                              ->setTo($address)   
                              ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => \Yii::$app->name])    
                              ->setSubject(' subject')   
                              ->setTextBody('...pdf attached..')   
                              ->attachContent($content,['fileName' => 'anyFilename.pdf','contentType' => 'application/pdf'])   
                              ->send();
   ```
4. Call again the function with parameter 'D' or 'I'. Send it to browser.

That's all.